# Problema ao criar projeto Angular

Tags: angular

Boa tarde pessoal, to começando programação e seguindo os passo a passo que me foi informado, na hora de criar um novo projeto pelo cmd, deu esse erro, vocês poderia me ajudar por favor???

mttttt obrigada!!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Oi,tudo bem? Esse problema é bem comum

Esse problema pode estar acontecendo devido a variável de ambiente não estar configurada

Vamos tentar resolver o seu problema, siga os passos:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli

Depois de instalar você entra em sistema

Configuração avançadas do sistema

Variáveis de Ambiente

Path

Editar
```

Se essas variáveis do Angular não estiverem no path, você adiciona fecha o terminal, abre e tenta rodar o comando novamente:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Matheus, acabei de testar e consegui!! muito obrigada mesmo!!!!! <3